Is Windows 10 "inactive' when Cygwin setup is running?
I initiated a Cygwin update and then stepped away from my home.  An hour later, I wiggled the pointer on the touchpad to wake up the display and saw that the progress bar at zero (though that the progress bar restarts at different stages of Cygwin's setup program).
An hour is a long time to update Cygwin on my system.  It could be a coincidence that I woke the display up just as the setup process entered a new stage and restarted the progress bar, but that would be quite the coincidence, especially since it finished shortly thereafter.
I wondered whether the laptop could have gone to sleep shortly after I stepped away.  I use different machines, and there are different actions needed to wake up a laptop.  This particular machine was set to never sleep when plugged in, but based on past experience, I don't necessarily trust Windows 10's ability to stick to my settings in the power options.
When there is no user action and the Cygwin setup is running, does that count toward inactivity time that eventually triggers a switch to sleep mode?  If so, then I need to troubleshoot why Windows is going to sleep after a period of inactivity, even though it is not supposed to when plugged in.
On the other hand, if the running setup program is not considered inactivity, then the reason for the (presumed) sleep mode is something other than a period of inactivity.

Windows shouldn’t go to sleep while an application like Cygwin is running. Your monitor might turn off but your monitor going to sleep and windows hibernating are two very different things. If your power settings are set so Windows never goes to sleep, Windows, won’t hibernate unless manually initiated by the user. Check the event logs….

OK, thanks.  Did you want to post your comment as the answer?  It does answer the question of whether execution of setup is considered by Windows to be inactivity.
